# KendoUI Grid with Observable MVVM Auto Select Row After Popup Edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using a Kendo UI grid with MVVM (observables).  I am trying to auto select a row after I create or edit it.  There is something happening after the "save" event that is clobber a call to the grid's select method.  My workaround is an obvious hack (but works for now), by setting a timeout of 100 ms to let all the events and such finish.  The Kendo docs don't seem to mention an event after "save" (like a "saved" method or some such).  Is there some such animal?  Can you think of a better way to do this (some place I could attach a callback would make me happier):

```
...
testRequestEdited: function(e) {
    var uid = e.model.uid;
    console.log(testRequestGrid.tbody.find(">tr[data-uid='"+uid+"']"));
    // some event happens after "save" that clobbers the select
    // this timeout is not the right way, but I will try it for now.
    setTimeout(function() {
        testRequestGrid.select(testRequestGrid.tbody.find(">tr[data-uid='"+uid+"']"));
    }, 100);
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The events triggered by adding new row:
`dataBinding` (before new row is added), `dataBound` (when new row is added), and then the new rows enter the edit state, immediately triggering `edit`event (from this point onward it behaves as normal editing). Then the `save` event is triggered when any changes are made to the dataSource, and that are all grid events.

However, after `save` there also happens one dataSource event - `change`. 
You can bind to it after grid initialization like this

```
$('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.bind("change",function(e)
  { 
    if(e.action=="itemchange")
    {
      console.log(e)
      //do your stuff
    }
   });
```

e: dataSource's `change` is the last event in the chain.

Comment: The "itemchange" is actually before the "save"... from console: "item changing" (from the datasource change eventhandler) then "save" (from the grids save event handler.

Comment: I just went to kendo demos page and bound 'save' to grid and 'change' to grid's dataSource and the 'change' was after 'save'

Comment: Hmmm.  I will have to play with this a bit more, because this is not the behavior I was seeing.  I am obviously doing something different...